# What is wrong with code - Trying to batch agent with similar account ID?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to batch Sales Invoice per customer . My agents are Invoice. I am looping through each of the account and checking how many invoices are there for each customer. Based on that changing the batch size. the batch Size calculated seems correct but the batching is not happening and batchSize is printed as 1 for each account.

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<MyAgent>> productsWaiting = new 
LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<MyAgent>>();

for (int i = 0; i < wait.size(); i ++){

MyAgent myAgent = wait.get(i);
int id = myAgent.actNo;
if (!productsWaiting.containsKey(id)) productsWaiting.put(id, new ArrayList<MyAgent>());
productsWaiting.get(id).add(myAgent);

 }

for (int key : productsWaiting.keySet())
{
int id= key;
 batchsize= productsWaiting.get(id).size();
 batch1.set_batchSize(batchsize);

 traceln("iD: " + id  + "   batchsize    "  +  batchsize);

    for (MyAgent p:productsWaiting.get(id)) {
      
        //System.out.println(x);
        //traceln("actNo" +p.actNo  );
        batch1.set_batchSize(batchsize);
        wait.free(p);
        batch1.set_batchSize(batchsize);
                      
        traceln(batch1.batchSize);
        
        //System.out.println("Released  " +"Batch Size  " + x + "account ID-" + id);
 
    }
    
}
```

Unable to change the batch size for each of account based on the invoices it contains.

Some logs are here

```
iD: 165691   batchsize    1
iD: 120895   batchsize    1
iD: 85295   batchsize    1
iD: 5080702   batchsize    2
iD: 121437   batchsize    1
iD: 174098   batchsize    1
```

On the entry of the batch block I checked the batach Size ..

```
165691

batch Size    1

120895

batch Size    1

85295

batch Size    1

5080702

batch Size    1

5080702

batch Size    1

121437

batch Size    1

174098

batch Size    1
```

Every entry of agent has batch size of 1..  Could you pls point out the mistake in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batching itself happens in a separate event and not inside the loop. Because you're calling the function `set_batchSize(int batchSize)` from the inside of a loop, your Batch block will only take the last value defined by this function as the batch size. That's why the batch size of every agent is 1.

The same also goes for the function `wait.free(Agent agent)`. This event will also take place only after you've finished calling the function to calculate the batch size.

So basically, instead of using a loop, you should only calculate the batch size for the next agent in the queue. Then you need to "wait" until the batching of this agent has taken place before you can calculate the batch size for the next agent.

Comment: I realized the same thing but how I can do it without loop.  Any reference for similar case?

Comment: I would get the first key from the collection productsWaiting (this doesn't work with keySet() though, but you can e.g. convert the set to a list), set the batch size, and free all required agents. You only need to do this for the very first agent. Then, after the first agent has finished the batching, you can call the same function in the on exit field of the Batch block and do the same thing but with the second key, etc.